# Inflate grid view in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I have display web data into listview using json parsing. So i have inflate gridview in custom row listview . But after set adapter in adapter of listview application crashed. Here is my image.... So which is the better way to display image like this. Use gridview or another way to display it??

[image: Here I am using static image but i want to display it with dynamically]

Comment: I will be stunned if a `GridView` in a `ListView` row will work well. That being said, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: Yes..But now i am trying to different...So please give me some suggestion how can i display like this...??